# Share data from view to controller

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to share data from a view to a controller in Ionic.

I actually have a form in the first view :

```
<form action="#/app/result" method="post">

    <select name="first">
        <option value="1">a</option>
        <option value="2" selected>b</option>
    </select>

    <select name="second">
        <option value="1">a</option>
        <option value="2" selected>b</option>
    </select>


    <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">Go!</button>
</form>
```

In my controller, I try to get the "first" and "second" post variables:

```
.controller('doSearchCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $http) {
  var first = $stateParams.first;
  var second = $stateParams.second;
 ...
}
```

But the $stateParams.first and $stateParams.second are empty anyway (I also tried to change the method to "get")

What is the best (and most efficient) way to pass these variables from the view to the controller? i saw some code using services but just for one variable, so cannot apply to this example...

Thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify what it is you're trying to achieve. Once you click `Go`, what do you want to see happen with your selected options? Do you want to store them for use by another controller? Do you just want to bind those variables to your `doSearchControl` scope? What are you using `$stateParams` for?

Comment: When I click Go, I want the selected options in the first and second select to be "posted" or given to the called controller "doSearchCtrl", so I can do, in this controller, a http call.

The answer will be given to an other view after that.

I use $stateParams to use the parameters given to the route when called!

Comment: you can use $scope.first or $scope.second

Comment: Nope, the $scope is used to send elements from controller to view, but not from view to controller :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately you do want to use a service to share variables between controllers/views. See the snippet below for my modifications.

A few notes:

1. I changed your code from using `forms`/`submit` to using `ng-click`, but you should use `submit` if it suits your purposes.
2. I used arrays to populate your dropdowns (`ng-options`).
3. If you want to bind data in your view to the view's controller, you can use `ng-model`. This sets up two-way binding for the `ng-model` variable/object, which will be available on that controller's `$scope`.
4. You should store your variables in a `service`, if you want to share it between views/controllers. You can use the getter/setter approach as shown in the snippet below.

When you click the button in the snippet, `controller 1` stores your selection in a service. You can extend this by adding another view/controller, and you will be able to retrieve these values from the service. Example code is shown in `controller 2`.

Hopefully this makes sense.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, letterService, $stateParams, $http) {
   
    $scope.firstList = ["a", "b"];
    $scope.secondList = ["a", "b"];
  
    $scope.set = function(first,second) {
       letterService.setLetters(first,second);
       alert("First letter = " + first + " and Second letter =" + second + ". These have been updated in letterService and can be called by any other controller in a different view");
      //You should put your http requests in a service, but you can execute it here/do routing.
    }
})

.controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, letterService) {
  
    $scope.firstLetter = "a";
    $scope.secondLetter = "b";
   
    $scope.get = function() {
       //get updated letters from letterService
       var selectedLetters = letterService.getLetters();
       $scope.firstLetter = selectedLetters.firstLetter;
       $scope.secondLetter = selectedLetters.secondLetter;
    }
})

.factory('letterService', function() {
   
 var selectedLetters = {}
 
    return {
 setLetters: function(firstLetter,secondLetter) {       
     selectedLetters.firstLetter = firstLetter;
            selectedLetters.secondLetter = secondLetter;
        },
        getLetters: function() {       
           return selectedLetters;
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Ionic Template</title>
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.2/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.2/js/ionic.bundle.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    </ion-content>
     <div>
         <select ng-init="first = firstList[0]" ng-model="first" ng-options="letter for letter in firstList "></select> 
         <select ng-init="second = secondList[0]" ng-model="second" ng-options="letter for letter in secondList "></select> 
         <button class="button button-small button-positive" ng-click="set(first,second)">Store these options in a service</button>
     </div>
    </ion-content>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! i cannot upvote your answer, but this solved my problem :)